# Update table in database using mysql/php when profile is edited by user

Tags: php, mysql

I am using local phpmyadmin as my database(MYSQL), I am doing something like this and i have no idea why this code is not updating the table in database. I am able to fetch data from database and show it on required page and place.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require('db.php');
    $id = session_id();
    $query = "SELECT * from new_record where id='" . $id . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Update Record</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form">
            <h1>Update Record</h1>
            <?php
                $status = "";
                if (isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new'] == 1)
                {
                    $id = session_id();
                    $name = $_POST['name'];
                    $age = $_POST['age'];
                    $submittedby = $_SESSION['username'];
                    $update = "UPDATE new_record SET    name='" . $name . "', age='" . $age . "', submittedby='" . $submittedby . "' WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
                    mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error());
                    $status = "Record Updated Successfully. </br></br><a href='personal-profile.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
                    echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">' . $status . '</p>';
                }else {
            ?>
            <div>
                <form name="form" method="post" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1"/>
                    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
                    <p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"/></p>
                    <p><input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Enter Age" required value="<?php echo $row['age']; ?>"/></p>
                    <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update"/></p>
                </form>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you done to try and actually debug this so far?

Comment: print query and run in PHPMyAdmin and paste result here.

Comment: make `var_dump($update);` to see if query is well formated

Comment: Note that you're open to sql injection. Now would be a good time to address that - but until you do, it would be nice to see the output of `echo $update` - and all those stops and starts (`."`) just slow down the execution of your code

Comment: what is `session_id()`?

Comment: While it dosn't solve the injection issue, I find this easier to read... `$update="
UPDATE new_record 
   SET name = '$name'
     , age = $age
     , submittedby = '$submittedby' 
 WHERE id = $id";`

Comment: maybe edditing the question we fix some syntax error? and its solved?

Comment: Check that line: $id = session_id();
Because you are sending ID with form via POST request but then instead of using it, you take session_id() to target row in DB (where I doubt that would be correct one).

Comment: I found somewhere that session.id() gives id of the current session so i thought i should give it to the variable.

Comment: I posted the query on phpmyadmin and its working fine.

Comment: I am not pro at doing this so there can be many errors. Please resolve or suggest.

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned in comments - take care of Injection issues.
2. session_id() taken into your $id does not have rows in your table. There are no rows in your table matching the MySQL Column id to the current session_id(). You will still have your form displayed with no values for name and age. When you fill and submit, it need to update an existing row which is not available in your table.